# linking to audiolab in python2.6 on osx

Tags: python, macos, scipy, scikits

I've been unable to get `scikits.audiolab` working on OS X.  I've tried `easy_install` and building from source, but both give me the same error:

```
----> 1 import scikits.audiolab

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/scikits.audiolab-0.11.0-py2.6-macosx-10.3-fat.egg/scikits/audiolab/__init__.py in <module>()
     23 __version__ = _version
     24 
---> 25 from pysndfile import formatinfo, sndfile
     26 from pysndfile import supported_format, supported_endianness, \
     27                       supported_encoding, PyaudioException, \

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/scikits.audiolab-0.11.0-py2.6-macosx-10.3-fat.egg/scikits/audiolab/pysndfile/__init__.py in <module>()
----> 1 from _sndfile import Sndfile, Format, available_file_formats, \
      2         available_encodings, sndfile_version
      3 from compat import formatinfo, sndfile, PyaudioException, PyaudioIOError
      4 from compat import supported_format, supported_endianness, supported_encoding

ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/scikits.audiolab-0.11.0-py2.6-macosx-10.3-fat.egg/scikits/audiolab/pysndfile/_sndfile.so, 2): Symbol not found: _sf_close
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/scikits.audiolab-0.11.0-py2.6-macosx-10.3-fat.egg/scikits/audiolab/pysndfile/_sndfile.so
  Expected in: dynamic lookup
```

`_sndfile.so` is created in the location it describes, so it's some weird problem linking to it as, far as I can see. Got me stumped. I'm on the point of abandoning audiolab.

I can't use the built in scipy  method for loading wavs as it doesn't work with 24-bit WAVs.

Answer (score 0):

Audiolab requires libsndfile. I had installed that via MacPorts, but it had built as x86_64 only by default.

Deleting all installs and reinstalling libsndfile with the `+universal` flag built it as i386 and x86_64.

Now I could install audiolab from source and it linked properly. :)