# Remove libsndfile module (Python, Mac OS X)

Tags: python, module, uninstallation, python-module, libsndfile

I want to uninstall libsndfile because I believe I installed the x86_64 version rather than i386, as per the answer [posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7919771/linking-to-audiolab-in-python2-6-on-osx). I didn't install libsndfile using MacPorts, so I'm not sure which way to do it.

How can I uninstall/remove/delete libsndfile?

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8346731/cleaning-python-modules-an-have-fresh-start-mac-os-x. It may be of greate help on removing python modules

Comment: Thanks, but I do not want to remove everything, just libsndfile.